# форматирования строки, разделение большого числа пробелом

Tags: python, format

Мне надо используя ТОЛЬКО `.format` вывести в консоль число 10000 разделенным пробелом 10 000
что-то типа:

```
item_name = 'Лампа'
total_quantity = '27'
total_amount = 1134
print('{0} - {1} штук, стоимость {2: d} рублей'.format(item_name, total_quantity, total_amount))
# Лампа - 27 штук, стоимость  1134 рублей
```

на выходе получилась 2 пробела, оно ставит пробел до числа. использовать `.replace` нельзя.
Искал и в документации, ничего про пробел не нашел

Comment: ну а split/join использовать можно?

Comment: @strawdog как хотите применить?

Comment: даже [pep 378](https://peps.python.org/pep-0378/) предлагает использовать ``.replace()``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = 10000
a_formatted = " ".join(('{0:,d}'.format(a)).split(','))
print('стоимость: {0}'.format(a_formatted))
```

> стоимость: 10 000

Comment: Почему я сам не додумался 
использовал без доп переменной, прямо внутри формат

Answer (score 0):

узнал про библиотеку `locale`. вот код:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
print('{0} - {1} штук, стоимость {2:n} рублей'.format(item_name, total_quantity, total_amount))
```

> Лампа - 27 штук, стоимость 1 134 рублей

да, оно работает и мне подойдет. Но можно ли обойтись без этой библиотеки, одним лишь форматированием?
Кстати, в консоли видим число с пробелом, но в pycharm этот пробел превращается в `NBSP` "неразрывный пробел", и все равно оно является строкой.

Comment: ``locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`` - это может работать иначе даже на соседнем компьютере, в котором другие настройки. У меня, например, там получается не пробел.

Comment: Так явно укажите локаль ru_RU)